# Нахождение словосочетания на сайте

Tags: python, парсер

Есть текст, из него мне нужно выбрать словосочетания которые например начинаются на "Он" и заканчиваются на "сделал" или "пошел".
Я совсем недавно начал заниматься парсингом и предполагаю что сделать это можно с помощью словаря, но как я не знаю. Спасибо заранее!

https://bible-teka.com/synodal/43/3/
Там есть два словосочетания "Он пришел"(2 строка) и "Он видел"(32 строка)

Попробовал через регулярные выражения

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

URL = 'https://bible-teka.com/synodal/43/1/'

all = requests.get(URL)
alltext = BeautifulSoup(all.text, 'lxml')
soup = alltext.find_all("div", class_="text")
    for souptext in soup:
            g = souptext.text
    print(re.search('пришел', 'g'))
```

Выводит "None"
Вот сайт: https://bible-teka.com/synodal/43/1/
Там есть целых 3 слова пришел
Не понимаю в чем проблема

Comment: Добавьте примеры текстов. Так-то такое просто сделать через регулярные выражения

Answer (score 0):

Ищите так:

```
print(re.search('пришел', g, re.IGNORECASE))
# <re.Match object; span=(320, 326), match='пришел'>
```

Вы ищете в строке `'g'`, а не в тексте из переменной `g`.